# App won't work in background when using dpkg to build my own package

Tags: ios, background, debian, dpkg

I write a jailbroken app using iOSOpenDev which can play audio in background when a timer fires.

When I use iOSOpenDev to build a .deb package, scp it to my iphone and install it using iFile, it works fine. But when I extract the .app to fold `~/temp`, control file to `~/temp/DEBIAN/` , build a .deb package using command `dpkg-deb -b ~/temp ~/myapp.deb`, install and run it. It won't play music in background untill I bring it back to foreground.

Did I miss something when building the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use scp and iFile.

With [iOSOpenDev](http://iOSOpenDev.com)'s command-line tool `iosod` there are commands to perform what you're trying to do:

`iosod build`: Builds a Debian package (does not require dpkg).

`iosod install`: Installs a Debian package on an iDevice.

There are even commands to remove and purge packages from an iDevice (`iosod remove`, `iosod purge`). To see all commands provided, in Terminal type `iosod`.

Answer (score 0):

I should not only use terminal when building package but also to extracting file, then we can avoid the Finder adding some files, such as .DS_Store, we don't need.

Comment: Note: If using `iosod` to build Debian package (which iOSOpenDev Xcode templates use), all '.*' files are filtered out and not included.